# Oracle Reports Builder 12 multiple page report

Tags: oracle, report, oraclereports

I have a report that spans 3 pages. When I run it for a parameter that may return more than one record, it returns all the page 1s first, then all the page 2s and finally all the page 3s.
I haven't been able to figure out how to format it so that it outputs page 1-3 for the first record, then page 1-3 for the second and so on.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way you described it, I think of 3 queries - each of them producing one of pages.

One of them (let's call it Q1) should be the "master" query, and others linked to it.

In Paper Layout Editor, Q1's repeating frame (R1) should enclose all other frames so that all data related to the 1st record are grouped together. Don't forget to set vertical elasticity properties (probably to "variable"), set page protect to "yes"; also, you'll probably want to set page break on all repeating frames so that they are printed on separate pages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's actually one query. It is a state regulatory report that has a lot of text and the fields are spread across the 3 pages.
I have a repeating frame for each page that is tied to the one query.

Comment: OK; but you have to have a "master" frame which contains them all. I'd try to "stretch" the first repeating frame so that it encloses all the others. Or, possibly, create a new "master" repeating frame which encloses all of existing ones.

Comment: I've already tried that and when you run the report to PDF it's all three pages in 1 8.5x11 page